# Format Python Pandas output to remove header characters

Tags: pandas, format

I have this code to scrape Institutional holding of a ticker

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

arg1 = 'AAPL'
statistics = pd.read_html(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+arg1+'/holders',index_col=1)
institutional_holding = statistics[0]
print(institutional_holding)
```

It always gives a 0 and 1 in start of output which I am unable to remove.  Sample outpout:

```
python mycode.py
                                            0
1
% of Shares Held by All Insider         0.07%
% of Shares Held by Institutions       59.66%
% of Float Held by Institutions        59.70%
Number of Institutions Holding Shares    4453
```

What is simplest way to remove 0 and 1 from output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:-

```
institutional_holding.index.names=[None]
```

you can rename 0 to 'Percentage' by:-

```
institutional_holding.columns=['Percentage']
```

And if you want to remove 0 then:-

```
institutional_holding.columns=['']
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I now have a cleaner output.